# How to handle multiple inputs to be editable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I added dynamic values to the multiple inputs in react and then I tried to edit that but it not at all editable. Here is the code :

```
class Hotels extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { id: 1, hotel: { name: "Sentido" } },
        { id: 2, hotel: { name: "Maris" } },
        { id: 3, hotel: { name: "Orka" } },
        { id: 4, hotel: { name: "Resort " } },
        { id: 5, hotel: { name: "Green " } },
        { id: 6, hotel: { name: "Maris" } },
        { id: 7, hotel: { name: "Nature " } },
        { id: 8, hotel: { name: "Diamond " } },
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return data.map((item, i) => (
      <input
        name={`hotel__${i}.name`}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        value={item.hotel.name}
        type="text"
      />
    ));
  }
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };
}
ReactDOM.render(<Hotels></Hotels>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

I do not use defaultValue property and I adde an onChange event, but it does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't simple to just update that index?

```js
class Hotels extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { id: 1, hotel: { name: "Sentido" } },
        { id: 2, hotel: { name: "Maris" } },
        { id: 3, hotel: { name: "Orka" } },
        { id: 4, hotel: { name: "Resort " } },
        { id: 5, hotel: { name: "Green " } },
        { id: 6, hotel: { name: "Maris" } },
        { id: 7, hotel: { name: "Nature " } },
        { id: 8, hotel: { name: "Diamond " } },
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.data.map((item, i) => (
      <input
        key={item.id}
        name={`hotel__${item.hotel.name}`}
        onChange={e=>this.handleChange(e,i)}
        value={item.hotel.name}
        type="text"
      />
    ));
  }
  handleChange = (event,hotelIndex) => {
    let data = [...this.state.data];
    data[hotelIndex].hotel.name=event.target.value;
    this.setState({data});
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hotels/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: React recommends **not** mutating state, which is what `data[hotelIndex].hotel.name = event.target.value` is doing. This works, but mutating state can lead to bugs fairly easy. For example if you where to pass `this.data` to a pure component it would never update, because the item array is always using the same reference.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Yes, you right. I made correction

Comment: @3limin4t0r  ,totally Is there any way to have handleChange function that not to be dependent on name of input?

Comment: @Maya I don't know why this answer changes the name without providing any details about *why* the change is made. The answer does not depend on the changed name and you can change it back to the original name without issue. Note that although the `data` array is now duplicated, the copy is a shallow copy and the answer still mutates state. I've also added my own answer, which creates a deep copy (but is more complicated).

Answer (score 0):

Your input name is incorrect. You should use `item.hotel.name`

```
render() {
    return data.map((item, i) => (
      <input
        name={item.hotel.name}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        value={item.hotel.name}
        type="text"
      />
    ));
  }
```

Then your handle change should be

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ data: this.state.data.map( item => {
        if (item.hotel.name === event.target.name) {
           return { ...item, hotel: { name: event.target.value }}
        } else {
           return item
        }
   }) })
  };
```

remember to add `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)` to constructor

Comment: Thank @Someone Special for your answer, Yes it is right but I forgot to mention that input name must be different in this issue, I have to have different name for each input , so I can not use this handle change?

Comment: traversing array using map is unnecessary here. Also, when you write your function as arrow function there's no need to bind that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { id: 1, hotel: { name: "Sentido" } },
    { id: 2, hotel: { name: "Maris" } },
    { id: 3, hotel: { name: "Orka" } },
    { id: 4, hotel: { name: "Resort " } },
    { id: 5, hotel: { name: "Green " } },
    { id: 6, hotel: { name: "Maris" } },
    { id: 7, hotel: { name: "Nature " } },
    { id: 8, hotel: { name: "Diamond " } }
  ]);

  const handleChange = (event, index) => {
    console.log(index);

    data[index].hotel.name = event.target.value;
    setData([...data]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <input
          key={item.id}
          name={`hotel__${index}.name`}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, index)}
          value={item.hotel.name}
          type="text"
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Please check my demo at CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-tree-zdij3?file=/src/App.js:58-933)

Comment: React recommends **not** mutating state. `data[index].hotel.name = event.target.value` mutates state. `[...data]` creates a shallow copy, nested object are copied by reference, and are not actually duplicated. Even if it where to deep copy, you mutate the state before creating the copy.

Comment: @3limin4t0r: You are right. But what should we do in this case? Just make a copy before mutating.

Answer (score 0):

Your items have an `id` attribute, so there is no need to use the array index in for example `` name={`hotel__${i}.name`} `` I suggest using the `item.id` instead. *id* is just an abbreviation of *identifier*, which is supposed to identify a resource.

With this recommendation out of the way, you have to pass an resource identifier to `handleChange` to identify which resource to change. This can be done in several ways.

1. Pass an identifier either the *index* or item *id*, alongside the event to `handleChange`.

   ```
   onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event, item.id)}

   // ...

   handleChange = (event, id) => {
     const name = event.target.value;
     this.setState((previous) => ({
       data: previous.data.map((item) => {
         if (item.id != id) return item;
         return { ...item, hotel: { name } };
         //    add `...item.hotel` ^ if hotel contains more attributes
         //    than just the name
       })
     }));
   };
   ```
2. This one has a lot in common with the first solution. You can created a curried version of `handleChange` with the *id* already provided.

   ```
   onChange={this.handleChange(item.id)}

   // ...

   handleChange = (id) => (event) => {
     // ...
   };
   ```

There are more than these two solutions to update state, but these are probably the most easy to grasp.

```js
class Hotels extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { id: 1, hotel: { name: "Sentido" } },
        { id: 2, hotel: { name: "Maris" } },
        { id: 3, hotel: { name: "Orka" } },
        { id: 4, hotel: { name: "Resort " } },
        { id: 5, hotel: { name: "Green " } },
        { id: 6, hotel: { name: "Maris" } },
        { id: 7, hotel: { name: "Nature " } },
        { id: 8, hotel: { name: "Diamond " } },
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.data.map((item) => (
      <input
        key={item.id}
        name={`hotel__${item.id}.name`}
        onChange={this.handleChange(item.id)}
        value={item.hotel.name}
        type="text"
      />
    ));
  }
  
  handleChange = (id) => (event) => {
    const name = event.target.value;
    this.setState((previous) => ({
      data: previous.data.map((item) => {
        if (item.id != id) return item;
        return { ...item, hotel: { name } };
        //    add `...item.hotel` ^ if hotel contains more attributes
        //    than just the name
      })
    }));
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hotels />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

The above snippet uses `` name={`hotel__${item.id}.name`} `` but you can use the original name if you can't change it or prefer to use the index.